# laravel 5.3 put, patch and delete routes. What are they and how to use them?

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I have knowledge of get and post routes but I want to learn how to use these routes (put, patch and delete) and what are their pros and cons. Till now I have used get and post to get, update or delete the record. I think it is not correct way to do it. Definitely they also have a purpose. If anyone can explain then please do it. Thanks.

Comment: Something in google? No?

Comment: [Resource controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers) may be of interest to you.

Comment: I want to write them manually because I want to learn about them thoroughly. resource is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to explain is show how REST API works.
Just imagine a book.

- GET /book - get one books
- POST /book - store a book
- DELETE /book - delete a book
- PATCH /book - modify book
- GET /books - get list of books
- POST /books - post many books
- DELETE /books - delete all books

Different method for different actions and no needs of naming it like:
'/getBook', '/deleteBook' and etc

Comment: I want to know about patch verb more.Will you please do it?

Comment: PUT replace object completely. It's like there was a book calling "harry potter" and author "JK Rowling"  and you have PUT (replace) it with new object "HTML5 book" author "unknown". In case with PATCH - you're updating partially - like only author or only book title

Comment: Okay! If I want to update a profile then I will see multiple input fields. If I only  change username and save changes then only username should be updated and other fields values should not be updated. To do this which HTTP verb is best? PATCH? and I will have to check it manually that which filed is changed and which is not or PATCH will automatically update only changed input fields  ?

Comment: PATCH is just method to determinate what's going on. The best way for your case is using PATCH, right but what fields would you send and what fields would be replace - that's only your choice. The core that you should use PUT only in case the object is totally different. Imagine a user who win a lottery and you have to replace a winner - you'd like to use PUT. If you just would like to update the winner email - use PATCH.

Comment: You mean only updating email will not rewrite the values that I am seeing profile settings form?